# Updating the value of a cell, part of a named range, does not update the dropdown referencing it

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, you can define a set of cells to become a named range.

And you can define, elsewhere in the document, a dropdown list whose options values are the ones from that named range.

---

So let's say your named range is defined in Sheet1 and contains the values "A","B","C",D".

And a dropdown list in Sheet2 proposes values from that named range, and the user chose value "A".

Now the user goes to sheet 1 and updates the cell containing the "A" value, so it becomes "AA".

Back to sheet 2, the dropdown list still contains the value "A" (now invalid), only a simple warning sign is visible.

Is there a way (a script, or an configuration option) to have an automatic update of the dropdown values matching a named range value that I am updating?

Comment: Quick question: can you reproduce that behavior on a different file? I've been testing it and it works for me

Comment: Here is a file containing exactly the result of the manipulation I describe: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JtXwMoY26W0GfHshoaqvFmkhx2MbBi2MtnFxcdn045E

Comment: Hey, can you change the permissions to 'anyone with the link'? I couldn't open the file

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you are wondering, but you can write a script to clear the contents of the cell with the dropdown values when any cell within the named range is edited.